# error: no match for ‘operator[]’

Tags: c++

```
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are  
‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ and ‘std::string’ {aka  
 ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’})  
   14 |     else{cout<<","<<some_vector[a];}  
      |                                ^
```

```c
/*bool check=true;
for(string i : some_vector){
    if(check==true){
    cout<<some_vector[i];
    if(i==5){check=false;}}
    else{cout<<some_vector[i]<<endl;}
}*/
bool boolF=true;
for (auto a : some_vector){
    if(boolF==true){
        boolF=false;
    }
    else{cout<<", "<<some_vector[a];}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы, похоже, не понимаете конструкцию

```
for(type e: container) {
```

В ней `e` принимает не значения индексов, а значения *элементов*!

В цикле вы вместо индекса пытаетесь использовать строку — что неверно. Строка у обычного вектора индексом не является...

Вероятно, вы хотели

```
bool boolF=true;
for (auto a : some_vector){
    if(boolF==true){
        boolF=false;
    }
    else{cout<<", "<<a;}
}
```

Comment: значит, чтобы вывести элемент вектора в цикле, нужно писать просто эту самую "е"?

Comment: @mendzek Смотря какой цикл Вы используете. Если ```for(type e: container) {``` то да, эту самую ```e```. А если используете ```for(int i=0; i<container.length(); ++i) {``` то для работы с элементом используете ```container[i]```